# How to set system Short Date to ISO format yyyy-MM-dd in Monterey?

Tags: monterey

I need to know how to set system Short Date to ISO format "yyyy-MM-dd" in Monterey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless they've moved it since Big Sur, the same way it's always been.

System Prefs > Language & Region > Advanced… > Dates
Drag to order.
Click any drop menu to change the 'style' 1 or 01, 22 or 2022 etc

[image]